# Prevent GUI Freezing and Enable File Reading

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have an academic project where I will do a lot of computations and put the output to a WPF `textBox`. Now I am really not versed in MVVM which I think is the correct way to solve this problem, but I am not looking for MVVM solution as the code structure doesn't matter, only the output matters.

So I need to do some computation on a remote file and this is how I am putting the output to the `textBox`:

```
private void btnParse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int geTimerDelay = int.Parse(txtDelay.Text);
    string ex = "";
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //access the URLs in a suitable interval and process data

        File.WriteAllText("data.txt",rootObject.timeSinceStartup.ToString());
    });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //access the URLs in a suitable interval and process data

        File.WriteAllText("data2.txt",rootObject.timeSinceStartup.ToString());
    });

    ...

    string ex = File.ReadAllText("data.txt") + "/n" + File.ReadAllText("data2.txt") ... ;
    txtOut.Text = ex;
}
```

Now is there any guarantee that my textBox will be populated only after all the necessary files have been generated? If not how can I do it (again by not freezing the interface!)

Is there a more simple and elegant way (again, I have no MVVM background, it's just academic code:( )?

Fact is that I need to run this subroutine every few seconds and update the textBox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such guarantee. Why not put all that functionality into just one task?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //access the URLs in a suitable interval and process data

    File.WriteAllText("data.txt",rootObject.timeSinceStartup.ToString());

    //access the URLs in a suitable interval and process data

    File.WriteAllText("data2.txt",rootObject.timeSinceStartup.ToString());
    string ex = File.ReadAllText("data.txt") + "/n" + File.ReadAllText("data2.txt")... ;

    txtOut.Text = ex;    
});
```

You'll need to correct the txtOut.Text assignment by looking up how to update the UI from a non-UI thread.

Comment: If you want to you could run those file write functions in parallel, if you need the speed. You'd need some means of triggering the reading of the files and updating the textbox only when all the file write functions have completed. There are many ways in which this could be done.